# Will lemon in a cheese dip work like melting salt?

Tags: sauce, cheese, citrus, melting, dip

I was looking at recipes for cheese dips and sauces. One of them mentioned that the specified lemon juice would make it 'markedly' more digestible. (The recipe is for [Nacho dip](https://heissehimbeeren.com/nacho-kaese-dip-selber-machen/) (in German) and uses 1 tsp lemon for 500 g of cheese, cooked up with milk & cream. Amounts are toward the end of that page.)

It occurred to me, would the presence of citric acid together with the cheese's salt amount to having sodium citrate in solution? The recipe does call for process cheese to begin with, but I guess the more melting salt, the less stiff the dip turns out, hence digestible. Or else, does the claim not hold or hold for another reason?

Comment: Not sure that'll work; normally you use sodium bicarbonate and pure citric acid to make sodium citrate.  But I've never tried.